# How to delete the first inserted item from database android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Let's say I am inserting three datas.
So iniitally, I am inserting trailer1, trailer2,trailer3.
Here id is auto increment.

```
id   trailer_number  trailder_id
1       trailer1       766
2       trailer2       899
3       trailer3       577
```

In this how can I delete the first inserted records from table.
I need to delete from button as trailer1 to be deleted first, then trailer 2 and then trailer 3.

I tried to use this but I always get 0.

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "trailer_table";
 public int getFirstId() {
        int _id = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"trailer_number"}, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
            _id = cursor.getInt(0);
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return _id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteDatabase mDb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String sql1 = "DELETE FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE id   =min(id);";
try {
 mDb.execSQL(sql1);
} catch (Exception e) {
} finally {
 mDb.close();
}
```

Every time you run this code will delete first item inserted

Comment: Thanks but It's not deleting. Still I can see all items in table.

Comment: Where you are seeing? It should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this statement:

```
delete from tablename
where id = (select min(id) from tablename)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dNHBKpSAbbK9a8Y5Qtpi43/0).
With Java code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
db.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_NAME + " where id = (select min(id) from " +  TABLE_NAME + ")");
```